# The difference between main and meta photography stack exchange sites.

Tags: support

I suspect this has been already asked but i am having issues finding a page about it and i am trying to understand the difference between the Main Photography site and the Meta Photography site? if this has already been asked, please point me to that question / answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The help dropdown at the top of the Meta site actually has a link to answer this for you... However: https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta as a shortcut. :)